# Comparing stdout and breaking out of loop to close a SSH connection

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, stdout

I am storing the log of a command executed over SSH to a file (logfile here):

```
while True:
 try:
  rl, wl, xl = select.select([channel],[],[],0.0) 
  if len(rl) > 0:

    stdout_data.append(channel.recv(65536))
    #print channel.recv(1024)
    logfile.write(''.join(stdout_data))
    logfile.flush()
```

Is it possible to read the data (preferably in a streaming method) and set a trigger based on a word (like 'Continue') to exit this process? I want to close the connection when I read 'Continuing'.

I am trying this with no result so far:

```
 elif(stdout_data == 'Continuing.'):
   break
```